# Can't see the binary after installing ruby gem: memcached

Tags: ruby, memcached, rubygems

I need to install and run memcached for an application. I have my own ruby installation on a linux machine I am not a super-user of.

My ruby installation is in ~/ruby-install which also has the ruby-gem binary installed. Now, from here, when I do a `gem install memcached', I do not see any error and it seems that the gem installation went well.

However, I'm a bit puzzled as to what post-install environment setup should I do to get the memcached commandline working?

Comment: What are the outputs you get from `gem environment` and `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute

```
cd `gem environment gemdir`
cd bin
ls
```

If that dons't display the program your looking for, I don't know whats wrong. Otherwise, just execute from here. All command line tools installed by Rubygems live here in the bin directory.

You can also add the gemdir to your $PATH. That will allow you to execute tools anywhere.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. It seems the gem did not install properly. I looked into the log and it says /usr/lib64/libgdbm.la not found. So, I installed the libgdbm on my own and exported it as LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/gdbm-install/lib; however, I still get the same error at the time of gem install. Any clues?

Comment: I have no clue what is going on then. My answer is what I have used in the past, but I have never worked with gems that require a lot of native libraries or low level C. I hope you find something.